# Question about TimeZones and Jquery CountDown plugin

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, javascript, jquery

I am looking to use this plugin: http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

but I need to use the TimeZone feature of it.  So I was looking at the sample code

```
$('#sydneyCountdown').countdown({until: liftoffTime, timezone: +10});
```

so +10 is the TimeOffSet number. Now I need to make it so I can do a jquery get request and grab the TimeOffSet from the server(which gets the users time from the db and does TimeOffSet).

However it seems that C# TimeOffSet returns something like this "+02:00"(not this is just a random zone not the same as the one in the jquery example).

So it seems like all the C# TimeOffSet follow that format +/-xx:xx

So I don't understand why the jquery plugin is only 2 digts while the other one is 4 digits.

Can I know off safley the last 2 digits in the C# tomatch the plugin format?

Edit - would this work?

```
            // working on how to get offsetTime will be posted soon.
            string time = "-08:30";      
            string[] split = new string[] {":"};
            string[] splited = time.Split(split, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            int hours = Convert.ToInt32(splited[0]);
            int mins = Convert.ToInt32(splited[1]);
            int totalMins = (hours * 60) + mins;
```

So just convert the hours to mins and then add the mins to it?

Edit - With offSetTime

```
   var info = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Tokyo Standard Time");
    TimeSpan span  = info.BaseUtcOffset;
    string time = Convert.ToString(span);
    string[] split = new string[] {":"};
    string[] splited = time.Split(split, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    int hours = Convert.ToInt32(splited[0]);
    int mins = Convert.ToInt32(splited[1]);
    int totalMins = (hours * 60) + mins;
```

Problem though OffSet only gives me the number not the +/- sign. So I don't know how to get it.

Edit -

Never mind I it makes sense that they don't add the plus sign since I was just testing one that would have a "-" sign and it is shown.

Comment: int totalMins = (hours * 60) + mins;
This won't work if hours is negative. You have to apply the same sign to minutes as well. Try: int totalMins = (hours * 60) + mins * Math.Sign(hours);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin says:

> Cater for time zones with the timezone
>   setting, which is set to the target
>   time's offset from GMT, in either
>   hours or minutes.

So, I think based on the magnitude of the timezone value, it treats it either as hours or minutes. You should convert the `<sign><hh>:<mm>` format to into number of minutes, to account for timezones that are not hour-aligned. Something like:

```
var tz = "-08:30";
var tz_tokens = /([+\-])0?(\d+):(\d+)/.exec(tz);
var tz_minutes = (tz_tokens[1] + 1) * (tz_tokens[2] * 60 + tz_tokens[3]);

// ..., timezone: tz_minutes, ...
```

Comment: Does anyone have a suggestion for a quicker way to convert the tz string to minutes? Make sure you account for "08" being treated as an invalid octal literal.

Comment: it also has something for UTC what if I am not mistaken is what the C# TimeZoneInfo uses?

Comment: hmm I don't even understand what that is doing. I am not very good with javascript.

Comment: I also probably would do this all in C# and send over the final number. I have to do a ajax request anyways so might as well use C# to send a final result over and not just a number that I have to then convert to get whatever is needed.

Comment: Yes! Doing the conversion to minutes in C# would be even better!